# How do you deselect the text in a rename dialog without moving the cursor, with the keyboard, in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, refactoring, rename

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 10.5.2

Example:

[image: code]

Say I want to rename this class to SomeAwesomeClass. 
If we do the Rename refactoring we get a dialog like this:

[image: rename dialog]

It has the cursor in the right place however the text is selected. So if we started writing "Awesome" the original name would disappear. So what I want to do is keep the cursor position but deselect the text.

I have not been able to find any way to do this. All things I've tried ether moves the cursor or removes the text or does nothing.

- Left or Right keys goes to the left or right.
- Up or down does nothing.
- Esc closes the dialog.
- PageUp or PageDown does nothing.
- Home or End goes to left or right.

The fact that the cursor is in the right place to start with makes me believe this is a existing feature...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In 11-eap (110.365) when you rename a class (Shift+F6):

1. at first full class name is selected and you have a dropdown with suggested names, press Esc
2. full class name is still selected (dropdown gone), press Esc again
3. you have class name unselected, and can write at cursor

Note a third Esc will exit rename.

In earlier versions (10.5.2) you can do a trick:

Before rename select one character (shift+arrow forward) where you want to end up (in SomeClass select C) then Shift+F6 and arrow back. I know it is a lot of keys to presses but in a long class name this helps.

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what I was looking for. In my version of EAP 2xx something it didn't work but after a update/patch it works so all is good now. And the trick will be very handle.

Comment: I've wanting the answer to this question for years, big thanks to Andreas and osundblad.